# How to I remove the options button at the top right of my android app

Tags: android, android-layout, navbar

I've created a slide in menu from the right but when I added this menu I also got another menu in the top right of the screen when pressed displays the same menu options as the slide in menu but they don't work.

How do I remove it without removing the slide in menu?

I have a hamburger menu button at the top left and a options three circle button on the top left.
I'm trying to get rid of the options button on the right

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, removing the `onCreateOptionsMenu` from your activity will do the job. All you need to do is delete the following method.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```